# Why there is Pig and Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, hbase, apache-pig, hdfs

I understood what are the components of Hadoop, but my question is:
As an end user, how can I access a file in Hadoop without worrying about the data storage?

So when using Pig/Hive commands, should I worry if the data storage is HDFS or HBase?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

First of all, HDFS is a file system and HBase a database so yes, you should take that into consideration, since you don't access them the same way.

Knowing that, Pig and Hive let you access the data much easier than in pure Java. For instance, Hive lets you query HBase in a close-to-SQL way.

In the same way, you can browse and manage files with pig almost like with a shell on a standart machine.

To conclude, you should not worry about **how** files are stored with Hadoop, but **where** they are stored (HDFS or HBase).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but consider I am a user, I want to connect to Hadoop, what are the steps?

Comment: @user3730681 The easiest would be to install pig and use it to connect to your Hadoop cluster. You'll find the needed documentation here : http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.12.1/start.html

Answer (score 0):

- HDFS is a distributed file system just like fxm said.
- Almost all of hadoop components built on HDFS.
- HBase is a DB which store its data on distributed file system (hdfs, can be other fs).
- Pig is a kind of programming language which will be generated to map reduce job.
- hive is a kind of db built on HDFS, and its SQL will be generated to map reduce job.
- Using udf of hive or pig, you can almost access any format data on hdfs.
- excuse my poor English. :D

Comment: Using PIG, I can store data in HBase. And HBase stores it data in HDFS. It means, I only talk to HBase using Pig, and HBase talks with HDFS automatically?

Answer (score 0):

Data in the **Hadoop** ecosystem needs to be stored in a distributed filesystem. **HDFS** is the most popular such filesystem.

But HDFS' value proposition is in offering *very high sequential read and write (scan) throughput*. What if you wanted fast random reads and writes ?

That's where HBase comes in. **HBase** sits on top of HDFS and enables *fast random reads and writes*.

But you store data to ask interesting questions about that data. That is where **MapReduce** comes in. You express your question in the MapReduce programming paradigm and it gets you the answer you need. But it's low-level and you need to be a programmer. **Spark** is an alternative to **MapReduce** - much better optimized for when you need to ask more sophisticated questions than MapReduce. **Hive** and **Pig** are higher-level abstractions than MapReduce. Hive let's you ask your question in SQL, and converts your SQL to MapReduce (or Spark) job. Although, with the growing popularity of Spark, you can skip Hive and use **SparkSQL** (Spark's Dataframe/Dataset APIs) which can also interpret SQL.

The difference between Hive and Pig is explained in this excellent [post](https://developer.yahoo.com/blogs/hadoop/comparing-pig-latin-sql-constructing-data-processing-pipelines-444.html) by Alan Gates (Pig project PMC member and author of Programming Pig).

Answer (score 0):

Pig is used when the data is unstructured and has no schema.
Database recommended - HDFS.

Hive is used when the data is structured and has a schema available.
Database recommended - Hbase.